# Starting one file after another in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm quite new to batch and I'm currently trying to run some Powerpoint presentations one after another. The thing is that I want it to look for all presentations that exists in my folder and then start one presentation after another. 
I did this with this line

```
for %%f in (/f E:\PP\*.pptx) do start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\PPTVIEW.exe" /F "%%f"
```

The problem now is that it runs every presentation at the same time. I kind of expected this already but I don't know how to manage that it does what I want to do.

Maybe you can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `start /w start "" "C:\Pr...`

Comment: That kind of worked but now it loops just the first file until I press esc..

Comment: Get rid of the `/f` inside the parenthesis `for %f in (E:\PP\*.pptx) do start /w "" "C:\Program..`

Comment: Already did that too, thanks. But that does not solves the problem of looping the first file over and over again.

Comment: please try `for %%f in (E:\PP\*.pptx) do echo %%f` and make sure there is actually more than 1 file, it should echo each file.

Comment: if there is more than one `pptx` file in that directory, my query below MUST work, I tested it and it does. I however have some `ppt` files in there aswell, which does not match, so I make it `*.pp*`

Comment: There are. If i press esc it will play the next presentation and so on.

Comment: well, that is what you asked it to do, wait for it to complete, then open the next. or do you want to open all, but with a delay?

Comment: It should play the second one automatically without anybody pressing a button. And then the third and so on.

Comment: copy the answer code below and try please.

Comment: Powerpoint doesn't work like a slideshow when trying to run multiple powerpoints.  You are basically trying to do something that it doesn't have capability to do.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one file, give a timeout of 5 seconds, open the next.

```
@echo off
for %%f in (E:\PP\*.pptx) do (
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\PPTVIEW.exe" /F "%%f"
timeout /t 5 >nul
taskkill /IM "PPTVIEW.exe"
)
```

keep in mind, this will open each 5 seconds after each other, but will not close the previous one, for that you need to run `taskkill` on the previous, before opening the new one.

For autoexit on a presentation (using powerpoint):

goto Options > advanced > untick the "end with blackslide" tickbox then simply run this code:

```
for %%f in (E:\PP\*.pptx) do start /w "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\PPTVIEW.exe" /F "%%f"
```

Comment: That's quite good, but now I need the first presentation to end before the second one pops in. The problem is that I don't know how long each presentation will be so I can't just make the timeout longer.

Comment: @Chrissichii copy edited code and try again.. why not stick with the `/w` and simply esc when done, the next will open..

Comment: If you actually wanted to do autoexit off ppt, then you would need to use powerpoint and set Options > advanced > untick end on black screen. which will then work much better with the `/w` option.

Comment: I used Taskkill. But it closes my presentation without being completely shown. I want it to show all slides and then close. With the timeout it closes before everything is shown and opens the next presentation.
And as I said I can't just make the timeout longer because there will be different presentations with different length.

Comment: well, we cannot guess the length of each presentation, so you will have to use powerpoint, set the options as I mentioned above.

Comment: I also use the Powerpoint Viewer, not Powerpoint. That's a thing I forgot to say..

Comment: I can see that in your code, but you need powerpoint to do that setting though.

Comment: Mh.. and there is no way to do what I want with the viewer?

Comment: I do not have the viewer, so cannot see if it has the "end with black slide" option. Open the viewer, see if it has advanced options, under options ad perhaps a black slide tickbox.

Comment: Then powerpoint is your only way, or doing the esc after it completed  using the `/w` switch.